# I am making Face Mask Detection and this error is given

Tags: python, pandas, keras, model, convolution

```
pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y_test , predict), columns=["No Mask","Mask"], index =["No Mask","Mask"])

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (2, 2)
```

How to correct this error

Comment: `confusion_matrix(y_test , predict)` is not of the correct shape. What is the output of `confusion_matrix(y_test , predict).shape`?